# Accessing object rather an object ID in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Using Devise, I can access an object's user with `SomeModel.user`, while the field is listed as `user_id` in the database schema. How can I do this with other ID fields? I have a model with two user fields; one from Devise, and a `guest_id` field. Can I use `SomeModel.guest` to access this second user object?

Answer (score 1):

Write this in your model

```
belongs_to :guest, class_name: "User"
```

Comment: That was easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want to add new relationship on SomeModel and in User.

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  # -- some code
  belongs_to :guest, class: User
  # -- some code
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # -- some code
  has_many :some_models, foreign_key: :guest_id
  # -- some code
end
```